# If $f\colon X\to S^k$ smooth, $X$ compact and $Z\subseteq S^k$ closed, then $I_2(f,Z)=0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I've been working through an old [example sheet](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/dg2e1.pdf) I found online at Cambridge geometry 2011, to fill in gaps in my topology.

The question #14 asks:

> Suppose $f\colon X\to S^k$ is smooth where $X$ is compact and $0<\dim X< k$. Let $Z\subseteq S^k$ be a closed submanifold of dimension $k-\dim X$. Show that $I_2(f,Z)=0$.

$I_2(f,Z)$ is the mod 2 intersection number, which is the number of points in $f^{-1}(Z)$ modulo $2$.

I scoured a somewhat handwavy explanation by Knutson. Since $\dim X<k$, there exists a regular value $p\notin f(X)\cap Z$. The idea is to then stereographically project away from $p$, and "pretend" $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}^k$. Then homotope to a constant by shrinking in $\mathbb{R}^k$ to get $I_2(f,Z)=0$.

My intuition is not strong enough to understand this explanantion. Can anyone more rigourously elucidate this explanation? That would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Do you know Sard's Theorem and the definition of regular value?

Comment: @TedShifrin I think so, Sard's theorem states the set of critical values has measure 0, and a regular value $p$ is one such that the derivative of $f$ is surjective at every point in the fiber of $p$. So I understand that such $p$ exists, it's mostly the stereographic projecting and homotoping that loses me.

Comment: What is $I_2(f,Z)$?

Comment: @user99680 It's the mod $2$ intersection number, I've put that in now.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a regular value, then $p\notin f(X)$ because of dimensions. We can moreover choose such a $p\notin Z$ (why?). You can stereographically project $\pi\colon S^k-\{p\}\to\Bbb R^k$. But the fact that $\Bbb R^k$ is contractible means that $I_2(\pi\circ f,\pi(Z))=0$. Note that $\pi$ is a diffeomorphism and mod 2 intersection numbers are invariant under diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Dear Ted, thanks! I'll try to verify these details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a couple of questions though. Why $p\notin f(X)$? I don't see how this follows from the dimension formula (in particular, $T_y f(X)$ needn't be defined since $f(X)$ needn't be a manifold if I understand correctly). Also, it seems in your answer you choose $p\notin Z\cap f(X)$ whereas your list of errata suggests that one needs to choose $p\notin f(X)\cup Z$.

Comment: @user500094 No one considers $T_yf(X)$, so I don't know where you got that.  One considers $df_x T_xX \subset T_{f(x)}S^k$. The linear map $df_x$ cannot be surjective, since $\dim X<k$, and so no value $f(x)\in S^k$ can be a regular value. And you're messing up your logic. To say that $p\notin f(X)$ *and* $p\notin Z$ is to say $p\notin f(X)\cup Z$.