# $I_2(X,Z) = 0$ for $X,Z$ manifolds in $\mathbb S^k$ of complementary dimension

Tags: differential-topology, transversality

> Suppose $f : X → \mathbb{S}^k$ is smooth, where $X$ is compact and $0 < \text{dim } X < k$. Then for all closed $Z \subset \mathbb{S}^k$ of dimension complementary to $X$, $I_2(X,Z) = 0$.

The hint is to use Sard's theorem to see that $\exists p \notin f(X)\cap Z$ and the stereographic projection.

My idea:

As $\dim X < k = \dim  \mathbb{S}^k$ we have that $\exists p \notin f(X)\cap \mathbb{S}^k$ and as $Z \subset \mathbb{S}^k$ then $ p \notin f(X)\cap Z$.  Now if we take the stereographic projection $P : \mathbb{S}^k / \{p\} \to \mathbb{R}^k$ we have that $P$ is a diffeomorphism and injective. So $P(Z)$ is a closed manifold in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

$I_2(X,Z) = I_2(i_X,Z) = I_2(f,Z) = I_2(P \circ f, P(Z))$

But as $P \circ f : X \to \mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathbb{R}^k$ îs contractible we have that $I_2(P \circ f, P(Z)) = 0 = I_2(X,Z)$.

So my question is, is Sard's theorem necessary to prove this?

Comment: Same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564799/if-f-colon-x-to-sk-smooth-x-compact-and-z-subseteq-sk-closed-then-i-2?rq=1)

Comment: The fact that such a $p$ can be found is a consequence of a simple version of Sard theorem